# React hook state has different values regarding several equal events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Ok, so I'm currently building a component to create quizzes.

So as a local state it has an array of sub-component that are used to create 1 questions and its possible answers.

I want it to give the possibility to create as much as new questions the user wants so that he can also remove a question he created while making the quizz.

The problem is here, I give my sub-component a function as props for it to call a remove action. It should be removing the component at the index of the sub-component which called it.

```
export default function QuizzManagement({sections}) {

    //const selectedSection = useSelector(state => state.classManagement)
    const [quizzList, setQuizzList] = useState([<QuizzCreator key={0} index={0} removeQuestion={removeQuestion}/>])

    useEffect(() => {
        //get quizz by section
    }, [])

    const addQuestion = () => {
        setQuizzList([...quizzList,<QuizzCreator key={quizzList.length} index={quizzList.length} removeQuestion={removeQuestion}/>])
    }

    function removeQuestion (index) {
        console.log(quizzList)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <SectionSelector sections={sections} />
            <div>
                {...quizzList}
            </div>
            <button onClick={()=>addQuestion()}>Add</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here I replaced the `removeQuestion` function mecanism to understand what was happening.

the sub-component:

```
<div>
            <textarea 
                placeholder="question ..." 
                value={question} 
                onChange={e => setQuestion(e.target.value)}>
            </textarea>
            <div>
                {inputFields}
            </div>
            <button onClick={()=> setAnswers([...answers, {text: "", isCorrect:false}])}>Add</button>
            <button onClick={()=>removeQuestion(index)}>Delete</button>
        </div>
```

Each quizzList logged is different:

```
Array [ {…} ]

Array [ {…} ]

Array [ {…}, {…} ]

Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
```

I only clicked once every question was created and sure the state was updated with the react dev tool.

I don't get it !

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7ikO.png)

Comment: You didn't really describe what was happening that you didn't want to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion, you should absolutely not be storing the components as your state -- rather, you should be storing the props you're sending the component as your state:

```
const [quizzList, setQuizzList] = useState([{index:0, key:0}]);

const addQuestion = () => {
    setQuizzList([...quizzList,{key: quizzList.length, index: quizzList.length}])
}
```

Then when you're rendering, do

```
{quizzList.map(qlo => (<QuizzCreator key={qlo.key} index={qlo.index} removeQuestion={removeQuestion}/>))}
```

HOWEVER, there's one thing I didn't correct -- I do not believe that you should be setting the key to `index`, and I don't believe you should be removing an item by `index` either. You should probably have a random string generated every time you add an element to the array, and use that as both they key and the thing you use in your `removeQuestion` function